# Error function SQL server to insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my code for function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fSubString](@pStudentID VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS @vStringTable TABLE( StudentNo int)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pStart INT, -- for substring , start
           @pLength INT; -- Length for @pStudent

   SET @pStart = 1;
   SET @pLength = DATALENGTH(@pStudentID);

   WHILE(@pStart <= @pLength)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @vStringtable    
       VALUES(SUBSTRING(@pStudentID, @pStart, CHARINDEX(',', @pStudentID, 1) - 1))

       SET @pStart = CHARINDEX(',', @pStudentID, 1) + @pStart;
   END

   RETURN
END
```

Execute this function

```
Select * from dbo.fSubString('1,4,2,3,6,5,4,3')
```

Works fine.

But this execution of that function causes problems:

```
 Select * from dbo.fSubString('33,4,44,3,6,5,74,3')
```

Comment: **Substring** Select * from dbo.fSubString('1,4,2,3,6,5,4,3') its work but Select * from dbo.fSubString('3344,4444,44,3,6,5,74,3') not substring why

Comment: this part of your function: `CHARINDEX(',', @pStudentID, 1)` is fixed. So the length of your substring isn't taking into account the actual length between commas. It works in your first example because every element is a one char length unlike your second example

Comment: ok ,how fixed this problem

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of better ways to split strings.  Do not re-invent the wheel.

See this article from Aaron Bertrand for a list of know ways.

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

For instance, if your data is XML safe, use this function.  Great for small data sets.  See performance metrics at end of article.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Here are the results of a sample call.  The function was stored in msdb.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4493b/1) for your function